# Using Colorbox on WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, colorbox

I could really use some help. I'm having trouble getting jQuery Colorbox to actually work on WordPress. I have installed it and I enabled "Automatically add colorbox-class to images in posts and pages." However, it is still loading the large image into a separate page. Here's example where I have color box installed: http://thebrlab.com/ugomozie/#!/chris-brown-prestige

Comment: As a sidenote, Wordpress already have Thickbox built in ?

Comment: ..and how do I use thickbox?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/ThickBox

Comment: Which plugin is it that you're using? (I've googled, there's a fair few Colorbox Plugins..)

Comment: jQuery Colorbox http://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-colorbox/

Comment: 1.) your header file 100% has `wp_head()`? 2.) "Since version 2.0, jQuery Colorbox’ automatic behaviour can be switched on and off in the settings - Default is Off" http://www.techotronic.de/plugins/jquery-colorbox/

Answer (score 0):

Hello i have used it on wordpress site you can check from here `http://www.maakasamentertainment.com/maa-kasam-entertainment`

the code which i used here simple

add script in head

`script src="domain/wp-content/themes/twentyten/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"`

and call class group1 where you want to show

`a class="group1" href="your_link/3118">`

I am trying to solve your problem
Check this link

`http://freeresource.in/2013/10/05/wordpress-custom-colorbox`

may this help

Thanks

anand

Comment: Do I add script to head in header.php?

Comment: Yes dear but its come on every place where you call header page if you havnt any issue with this you can use it..

Comment: I had tried adding the colorbox js and css to the header.php and still having issues.

Comment: http://freeresource.in/2013/10/05/wordpress-custom-colorboxinsert on page where you want to show <script type="text/javascript"> var $s = jQuery.noConflict(); $s(document).ready(function(){ //Examples of how to assign the ColorBox event to elements $s(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'}); }); </script>